# monacaデバッグビルドのインストールについて

Tags: ios, monaca, iphone

monacaでiosアプリを開発しているのですが、デバッグビルドを行ったアプリがインストールできず困っています。

iTunesからiPhoneにアプリのファイルを入れても、アプリは「インストール中」の表示が出たまま固まってしまいます。(アイコンはプログレスバーが表示されず、薄暗いままです)

何度か同期をするとインストールのプログレスバーが表示され、インストールが進むのですが、残り四分の一くらいで最初の「インストール中」の状態に戻ってしまい、インストールが完了しません。

使用している実機はiPhone6で、バージョンはios9.2.1です。

何が問題なのか全くわからず、どう対処すればよいのかとても困っています。
どうかご回答の程よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: インストールを行おうとしている端末のUDIDは登録済みですか？インストールできない理由の一つとしてUDIDが未登録と言うのがあります

Comment: Myakuさん、コメントありがとうございます。UDIDの登録というのは、iOS Dev Center上で開発用端末を登録する際に入力するものですよね？その時は入力しましたが、ほかにUDIDを登録しなければいけない場面があるのでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、先ほどiOS Dev Centerにて登録した端末のUDIDを確認したところ、間違えて登録していました…。改めて登録しなおし、無事インストールすることができました。しょうもないミスでお恥ずかしい限りですが、おかげで間違いに気づくことができました。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: インストール出来たようでなによりです。回答として纏めておきました。改めて確認してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDIDの間違いだったようでなによりです。
問題解決のための確認と、再発防止について少しお話しさせていただきます。

**UDIDミスタイプについて**
まず、UDIDの登録の際にUDIDは手打ちしてはいけません。
なぜなら、ミスタイプを誘発するからです。
UDIDの表示のさせ方はご存知かと思います。
いくつか方法は有りますが、確実なのはiTunesを利用することでしょう。
iTunesからUDIDを表示させた際に右クリックでコピーを選択することで
登録時に張り付けするだけで済みます。
この手順では入力が無いのでUDIDの登録ミスは無くなるかと思います。

---

**登録したUDIDが変わってしまうタイミング？？？**
変わってしまうタイミングと記載しましたが、端末のUDIDは変更されることは有りません。
代わりに、ややこしいながらUDIDが違うことに気づかないタイミングがあります。
下記のタイミングそれぞれで忘れないように端末を登録しましょう。

１．本体が液晶割れや故障などで交換となった場合
(Appleのサポート対象のお店では基本的に交換対応ですので液晶割れだけでもUDIDが変わりますね)
２．新しい端末に機種変更を行った場合
(iPhone6からiPhone6sに変更などすると似た端末なので気づきづらいです。)
３．複数端末を同時にテスト端末として運用しようと新規購入した場合
(これはどうしようもないです。新規端末を手に入れる際に忘れずに逐次登録することです。)

---

**mobileprovisioningファイルについて**
ビルド時に必要になるファイルですが、此方のファイルの中に端末のUDIDが含まれています。
こちらのファイルの管理が出来ていないと複数の`mobileprovisioning`ファイルに悩まされ
結果、目的とする端末が含まれていない`mobileprovisioning`ファイルでビルドしてしまい
インストールできないという問題が発生します。

１．新しい端末(UDID)を登録するたびに`mobileprovisioning`ファイルを作成する
UDIDを含んでいるファイルですので端末に変更があった場合には編集しなくてはなりません。
２．`mobileprovisioning`ファイルの名称に年月日を含め、変更時に逐次リネームする
年月日を含めることで一番最新のものを明確にします。
せっかく`mobileprovisioning`ファイルを編集しても最新ファイルが分からなければ意味が無いです。
３．`monaca`にキャッシュ(保存)されているファイルは信用しない
`mobileprovisioning`ファイルを保存してくれる機能は確かに便利です。
次にビルドするときにも同じ`mobileprovisioning`ファイルなら良いのですが、
別のプロジェクトだったり、端末が新規に追加された場合には`mobileprovisioning`ファイルを変更しなくてはなりません。
キャッシュされている`mobileprovisioning`ファイルが最新か怪しい場合は直ぐに上げなおしましょう。

---

以上です。お心当たりはありますか？
改めて確認していただければミスも減るかと思います。
参考になれば幸いです。